# Is there a way to access Stata from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, stata

… similar to the [StatET](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) plugin that allows you to run R code from Eclipse?

I tried googling it but nothing useful has turned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that I know. If you're a CLI junky or willing to use Emacs, you might find limited support through the [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) package and the [ado-mode](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s392901.html). This is what I used on Mac OS X when I want to run short snippet of code, or use Stata in batch mode, but there's no interactive graphical output (you can just save graphics as PDF as usual). The `ado-mode` provides basic syntax highlighting and can send region or buffer to a running instance of Stata GUI program (not the executable file, `stata-*`, that is being used by `ESS`).

Here are two screenshots of (top) edition of code in Emacs with the ado-mode, and (bottom) an interactive Stata session (no plot produced).

[image]

[image]

[Some notes on text editors for Stata users](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/texteditors.html) provides a list of text editors that can be used with Stata (without interactive facilities, though).

Comment: Alright. There really seems to be no way to do it interactively. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a promising project starting up here:
http://mas802.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/stata-plugin-for-eclipse-alpha/